# problem executing ffmpeg in node-rstp-stream

Tags: rtsp

> rstp-stream (  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-stream ) and
>   execute in a -js file the following configuration: Stream =
>   require('node-rtsp-stream'); stream = new Stream({   name: 'name',
>   streamUrl: 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov',
>   wsPort: 9999,   ffmpegOptions: {
>            '-stats': '',
>            '-i': 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov',
>            '-force_fps': 30,   } });

I have the following error when executing it :

> ffmpeg version 4.1-1~18.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
>   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~18.04.york0'
>   --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100   libavcodec     58. 35.100 /
>   58. 35.100   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0   libswscale      5.  3.100 / 
>   5.  3.100   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100 Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov':   Metadata:
>       title           : BigBuckBunny_115k.mov   Duration: 00:09:56.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 12000 Hz, stereo, fltp
>       Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 240x160, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc Input
>   #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov':   Metadata:
>   title : BigBuckBunny_115k.mov   Duration: 00:09:56.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
>   Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 12000 Hz, stereo, fltp
>   Stream #1:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 240x160, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc : No
>   such file or directory

In the output it says : "No such file or directory".
I have been investing and didn't find any info about it.
Any idea on how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

run the server with administrative privileges.
make sure that running ffmpeg is included and running in the PATH environment variable.